# How do i add a custom web part property with a dropdown list

Tags: web-part, properties

How would i do this for a system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart, i have found many articles showing how to do this for microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart but this wont work for the system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.webpart.

I have a list of values i want to show in the drop down which come from a multiple lists, so i cant use an enum.

Answer (score 1):

Well if its not an enum and it comes from different sources you have to create a toolpart.

There are some things that cannot be done with the new namespace, you have to resort to using the older one.  Things like enhanced connections and most likely toolparts, although I cant recollect where the list that states them all is.

If I were you just use the older namespace.